# On Text Changed Client side event in telerik textBox to access a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Hi there is a Telerik grid. and inside it there are two textBox Columns named sign in time and sign out. finally there is a label column too, to have the hours from the time signed in to sign out. that should be calculated and shown as other two textBox values change. What should i do ?
below js function is called in onkeypress of txtsignout textbox

```
var grid = $find("<%= rdgDriverTimeSheets.ClientID %>");
if (grid) {         
    var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
    var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
        var row = Rows[i];
        var signIn = row.findControl("txtSignIn").get_value();
        //var signOut = args.get_keyCharacter();
        var signOut = row.findControl("txtSignOut").get_value();
        // var hours = signOut - signIn;
        //row.findControl("lblHours").set_value(hours)
    }
}

<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" DataKeyNames="Id" EditFormSettings-EditColumn-Visible="false" EditFormSettings-EditColumn-Display="false" PageSize="20" AllowFilteringByColumn="false" AllowPaging="true">
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"></PagerStyle>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="10px" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Customer" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="150px"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AllocatedDate" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="80px" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SignIn" HeaderText="Sign-In" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">   </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SignOut" HeaderText="Sign-Out" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="50px" UniqueName="txtSignIn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSignIn" runat="server" Width="50px"></telerik:RadTextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="50px" UniqueName="txtSignOut">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSignOut" runat="server" Width="50px"></telerik:RadTextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Width="50px" BorderColor="#000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Height="20px"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlServices" runat="server" Width="150px" DefaultMessage="Select..."></telerik:RadDropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
```

Comment: First you should post your code. What have you done so far...

Comment: suree i will post it down

Comment: Please edit your question and add code there

Comment: Post ASPX grid markup also

Comment: appreciate any help . please..

Comment: are getting value in this - var signIn = row.findControl("txtSignIn").get_value();

Comment: yup i  get the value in it and cannot get the valu e of the text box of which has the onkey press function called. By the way i have called it on txtsignout textBox

Comment: any one got a solution for this please :)

Comment: Refer this post which is very similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584150/keypress-event-for-radnumeric-textbox-in-radgrid-for-exchanging-coloumn-values

Comment: @RahulNikate sorry i dont have enough reputation to vote you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this post which very similar to yours.

[KeyPress event for RadNumeric Textbox in Radgrid for exchanging coloumn values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584150/keypress-event-for-radnumeric-textbox-in-radgrid-for-exchanging-coloumn-values)

Also, Check below link which will help you in getting controls at client side.

http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/07/access-radgrid-on-client.html#634843672348620742

Comment: Hi Rahul in the example you have provided it uses a value changed event not the keypress i need to calculate the hours when ever change signin or sihnout text change

Comment: You can change event like onkeypress="ValueChanged" on your textbox

Comment: yeah but it's not gonna work out as it is supposed to be

Comment: You can define like this. <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="ValueChanged" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>

Comment: what is that PreventPostback

Comment: I think using key press will not work in your scenario. Better go with this. <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"> <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="ValueChanged" /> </telerik:RadTextBox>